# XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model error after migrating to Java 8 on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8, google-cloud-platform, java-7

After migrating to Java 8 you may see this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model
```

Answer (score 4):

The `XPathFactory.newInstance()` method from Java8 with an older release of Saxon (< 9.5.1.5) on the classpath will cause this failure. To fix the issue you need to upgrade to a newer version of Saxon. The current version is 9.9 and is available in the Maven Repository and the Saxon website.

For more info on Java 8 for Google App Engine, see
[Migrating to Java 8](https://cloud-dot-devsite.googleplex.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8).