# Maven exec plugin and calling XPathFactory.newInstance()

Tags: java, maven

I'm using Maven's exec plugin to run custom code generation like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
        <mainClass>a.b.GenerateClasses</mainClass>
        <arguments>
            <argument>${project.basedir}/src/main/wsdl</argument>
            <argument>-output</argument>
            <argument>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wsdl</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Inside this class the following method gets called `XPathFactory.newInstance()`. This does not yield the correct result. Instead I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to
> create an XPathFactory for the default object model:
> http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the
> XPathFactoryConfigurationException:
> javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: No XPathFctory
> implementation found for the object model:
> http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom

Any ideas? I'm running Java 21.

Comment: I'm not an expert in GCP, but I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245635/xpathfactorynewinstance-failed-to-create-an-xpathfactory-for-the-default-obje may be helpful.

Comment: I recommend to check https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found a solution. I just use goal `exec? instead of` java`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath/>
            <argument>a.b.GenerateClasses</argument>
            <argument>${project.basedir}/src/main/wsdl</argument>
            <argument>-output</argument>
            <argument>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wsdl</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I recommend writing custom Maven plugins rather than using generic ones. This isn't very complicated. This case could be the perfect starting point for writing custom plugins, you'll just need a POM and a single MOJO. The advantages, especially in a team are clear configuration parameters, no need to care about the class path and the extremely practical standardized plugin documentation. On the other hand, the major problem is to set up an infrastructure for distributing them (custom, team wide Maven repository and the knowledge how to deal with Maven releases).